# How do I access the managed accounts data in an android phone?

Tags: android

Under >>Settings >>Accounts & sync >>Manage accounts, the user can enter numerous accounts to be streamed to the phone. How does one get programmatic access to this list? Thanks ...

Comment: Ok, I've got access to the list of accounts via 'AccountManager.get(context).getAccounts();' but I still can't get any of the details other than name and type! I need to get to the account password. Any thoughts ???